# React focus on an input element that have input with disabled property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input element with disable true. Now once i click on a button i want to set the disabled to false and focus on the input element.

I have tried the useRef option as described on react docs and it works if i removed the disabled property but both of them don't work together.

```js
const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);
const searchInput = useRef(null);
return (
  <>
    <input
      ref={searchInput}
      type="text"
      name="wnique_name"
      id="unique_id"
      disabled={!edit}
    />

    <button
      onClick={() => {
        setEdit(true);
        searchInput.current.focus();
      }}
    >
      Edit
    </button>
  </>
);
```

Comment: `disabled` elements are not focusable - see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled). You probably want the `readOnly` attribute rather than `disabled`, if it should be not editable but still focusable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `useEffect` to check when the input is enabled.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (edit) {
      searchInput.current.focus();
    }
  }, [edit]);

  return (
    <>
      <input
        ref={searchInput}
        type="text"
        name="wnique_name"
        id="unique_id"
        disabled={!edit}
      />

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setEdit(true);
        }}
      >
        Edit
      </button>
    </>
  );
```

Comment: why is useEffect needed?

Comment: Actually focus property should be triggered after the input field has disabled. Therefore useEffect is used (We know that useEffect runs after the component has finished rendering).

Answer (score 0):

The components need to rerender and "enable" the input.
Quickfix with setTimeout:

```
 onClick={() => {
  setEdit(true);
  setTimeout(() => {
     searchInput.current.focus();
  })
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can imperatively tell the onClick to make the input disabled false.

```
<button
  onClick={() => {
    setEdit(true);
    searchInput.current.disabled = false;
    searchInput.current.focus();
  }}
>
  Edit
</button>
```

</>
);